# Regex for integers delimited by commas

Tags: c#, regex

I need a `Regex` that only allows Integers (positive and negative) delimited by comma `2,-3,4`, but the comma should only be in the middle of two integers, *not* at the start or end or two consecutive commas like `23,34,,4`.

Currently I have this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d{1,10}([,]\d{10})*$");
 if (!regex.IsMatch("123,34,2,34,234"))
```

But it doesn't seems to match any thing it even rejects valid inputs like `123,34,2,34,234`

Can you please point out what is wrong with my above regex.

Comment: `\d{10}` only matches 10-digit chunks. Did you mean `@"^\d{1,10}(,\d{1,10})*$"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\d{10}` subpattern only matches 10-digit chunks.

You need to allow 1 to 10 with `{1,10}` (or 1 and more with `+`) with

```
@"^\d{1,10}(?:,\d{1,10})*$"
```

or

```
@"^\d+(?:,\d+)*$"
```

Note the use of a non-capturing group `(?:...)` that does not store the submatches, and is only meant to group a sequence of subpatterns.

See  the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cd%7b1%2c10%7d%28%3f%3a%2c%5cd%7b1%2c10%7d%29*%5cr%3f%24&i=123%2c34%2c2%2c34%2c234%0d%0a123%2c34%2c2%2c34%2c%2c234%0d%0a123232435&o=m)

EDIT: To allow matching negative values, add an optional `-`:

```
@"^-?\d+(?:,-?\d+)*$"
   ^^       ^^
```

See [another regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5E-%3F%5Cd%2B%28%3F%3A%2C-%3F%5Cd%2B%29*%5Cr%3F%24&i=123%2C34%2C2%2C34%2C234%0D%0A123%2C34%2C2%2C34%2C%2C234%0D%0A123232435%0D%0A2%2C14%2C124%2C-124%2C2&o=m).

Comment: This does everything fine, except it doesnt allow negative integers. According to it `2,14,124,-124,2` is an invalid input but `2,14,124,124,2` is correct.

Comment: Just add the optional hyphens to the pattern, `-?`. The `?` quantifier matches 1 or 0 occurrences of the quantified subpattern.